# [C#]Export DatagridView in xls for openOffice Calc

Tags: c#, excel, export, export-to-excel, openoffice-calc

I have this function that export a datagridView in Excel sheet :

```
 public void ExportGridToExcel(DataGridView TheGrid, string FileName)
    {

            using (System.IO.StreamWriter fs = new System.IO.StreamWriter(FileName, false))
            {
                fs.WriteLine("<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>");
                fs.WriteLine("<?mso-application progid=\"Excel.Sheet\"?>");
                fs.WriteLine("<ss:Workbook xmlns:ss=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet\">");
                fs.WriteLine("    <ss:Styles>");
                fs.WriteLine("        <ss:Style ss:ID=\"1\">");
                fs.WriteLine("           <ss:Font ss:Bold=\"1\"/>");
                fs.WriteLine("        </ss:Style>");
                fs.WriteLine("    </ss:Styles>");
                fs.WriteLine("    <ss:Worksheet ss:Name=\"Sheet1\">");
                fs.WriteLine("        <ss:Table>");
                for (int x = 0; x <= TheGrid.Columns.Count - 1; x++)
                {
                    fs.WriteLine("            <ss:Column ss:Width=\"{0}\"/>", TheGrid.Columns[x].Width);
                }
                fs.WriteLine("            <ss:Row ss:StyleID=\"1\">");
                for (int i = 0; i <= TheGrid.Columns.Count - 1; i++)
                {
                    fs.WriteLine("                <ss:Cell>");
                    fs.WriteLine(string.Format("                   <ss:Data ss:Type=\"String\">{0}</ss:Data>", TheGrid.Columns[i].HeaderText));
                    fs.WriteLine("                </ss:Cell>");
                }
                fs.WriteLine("            </ss:Row>");
                for (int intRow = 0; intRow <= TheGrid.RowCount - 2; intRow++)
                {
                    fs.WriteLine(string.Format("            <ss:Row ss:Height =\"{0}\">", TheGrid.Rows[intRow].Height));
                    for (int intCol = 0; intCol <= TheGrid.Columns.Count - 1; intCol++)
                    {
                        fs.WriteLine("                <ss:Cell>");
                        fs.WriteLine(string.Format("                   <ss:Data ss:Type=\"String\">{0}</ss:Data>", (TheGrid.Rows[intRow].Cells[intCol].Value != null) ? TheGrid.Rows[intRow].Cells[intCol].Value.ToString() : string.Empty));
                        fs.WriteLine("                </ss:Cell>");
                    }
                    fs.WriteLine("            </ss:Row>");
                }
                fs.WriteLine("        </ss:Table>");
                fs.WriteLine("    </ss:Worksheet>");
                fs.WriteLine("</ss:Workbook>");
            }
}
```

If i try to open the generated XLS with Microsoft Excel everything is ok, but if try to open with OpenOffice Calc, give me an import screen and i can't open the spredsheet.

Why ?
How can i do for export an Excel sheet compatibile with openoffice calc ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, it seems that you are saving an xml file as xls. Microsoft Excel can open the xml files, whereas *probably* Calc cannot. I'd suggest you create excelsheet using [Excel object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa189754%28v=office.10%29.aspx) and then try opening it in Calc. This [example](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/grid/ExportDatagridviewToExcel.aspx) might help.

Comment: Yes, but for using Excel Object i need Office installed on the user computer, How can i check if the office is installed on the user computer?

Comment: @aleroot: Not necessarily, if you include the referenced assembly in the output of the project then you won't need Office to be installed on the user's computer. CSV may, however, be an easier choice if you need compatibility for both excel and calc though.

Comment: No, you need to have Excel installed on every machine otherwise you get an error on COM component ...

Answer (score 1):

I would imagine you have, but I am wondering if you have considered exporting to a CSV format. Both OpenOffice and Excel (and anything else that can import a CSV) would then be able to open the file, though you may lose some of your formatting options.

Answer (score 0):

please find this working code you need to close the Filestream fs.close()

StreamWriter fs = new StreamWriter(Application.StartupPath + "\Export.xls", false);

```
                    fs.WriteLine("<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>");
                    fs.WriteLine("<?mso-application progid=\"Excel.Sheet\"?>");
                    fs.WriteLine("<ss:Workbook xmlns:ss=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet\">");
                    fs.WriteLine("    <ss:Styles>");
                    fs.WriteLine("        <ss:Style ss:ID=\"1\">");
                    fs.WriteLine("           <ss:Font ss:Bold=\"1\"/>");
                    fs.WriteLine("        </ss:Style>");
                    fs.WriteLine("    </ss:Styles>");
                    fs.WriteLine("    <ss:Worksheet ss:Name=\"Sheet1\">");
                    fs.WriteLine("        <ss:Table>");
                    for (int x = 0; x <= dgvReport.Columns.Count - 1; x++)
                    {
                        fs.WriteLine("            <ss:Column ss:Width=\"{0}\"/>", dgvReport.Columns[x].Width);
                    }
                    fs.WriteLine("            <ss:Row ss:StyleID=\"1\">");
                    for (int i = 0; i <= dgvReport.Columns.Count - 1; i++)
                    {
                        fs.WriteLine("                <ss:Cell>");
                        fs.WriteLine(string.Format("                   <ss:Data ss:Type=\"String\">{0}</ss:Data>", dgvReport.Columns[i].HeaderText));
                        fs.WriteLine("                </ss:Cell>");
                    }
                    fs.WriteLine("            </ss:Row>");
                    for (int intRow = 0; intRow <= dgvReport.RowCount - 2; intRow++)
                    {
                        fs.WriteLine(string.Format("            <ss:Row ss:Height =\"{0}\">", dgvReport.Rows[intRow].Height));
                        for (int intCol = 0; intCol <= dgvReport.Columns.Count - 1; intCol++)
                        {
                            fs.WriteLine("                <ss:Cell>");
                            fs.WriteLine(string.Format("                   <ss:Data ss:Type=\"String\">{0}</ss:Data>", (dgvReport.Rows[intRow].Cells[intCol].Value != null) ? dgvReport.Rows[intRow].Cells[intCol].Value.ToString() : string.Empty));
                            fs.WriteLine("                </ss:Cell>");
                        }
                        fs.WriteLine("            </ss:Row>");
                    }
                    fs.WriteLine("        </ss:Table>");
                    fs.WriteLine("    </ss:Worksheet>");
                    fs.WriteLine("</ss:Workbook>");
                    fs.Close();
```